onMount not being called / Component is mysteriously not being rendered
I'm trying to make an Aternos clone with solid-start with rust backing up most of the functionality, using bun:ffi for my needs and compiling my rust code into a shared lib.
export default function About() {
  const [version, setVersion] = createSignal("Loading...");

  onMount(() => {
    console.log("onMount triggered");

    // FFI function from Rust
    const version = getBackendVersion();
    setVersion(version);
  });

  return (
    <main>
      <Title>About MCS</Title>
      <p>Running {version()}</p>
    </main>
  );
}

as seen in the onMount line, im expecting a onMount Triggered message on my browser devtools but i seemingly get nothing. which leads me to the conclusion that my component isnt being rendered. this is backed up by the fact that the title hasnt changed
I've tried to make a test function and use that instead of getBackendVersion to no avail:
function getVersion() {
  return "dummy";
}

any reasons as to how this happens?
